# How to redirect to another page and refresh it in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

On button click i am calling a function like this

```
<a href="#" ng-click="submit()">Submit</a>
```

My controller code is like this

```
$scope.submit = function(){
    $state.go('app.calendar');
}
```

This code is taking me to calendar page. But after that page should reload. Can anybody help me..

Comment: What do you mean `that page should reload` ? Do you have a controller on `app.calendar` route?

Comment: Check out my answer @Santhosh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this::

```
$scope.submit = function(){
  $location.path('/calendar'); //need to add the path of calendar page
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is woking

Comment: Thanks @SanthoshAineri

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for

```
$state.go('app.calendar', {}, {reload: true})
```